# Can fluid respect soft bodies (or any deformation!) in blender?

Tags: modifiers, fluid-simulation

Right now, I have a render that looks something like: [this](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2u4ojs0%3E&s=5#.UuFy2RDna1s).

As you can see, the fluid is ignoring the soft body simulation.

Is there any way I could make the fluid respect the soft body simulation?  It doesn't need to be *good* - this isn't an engineering project - but the fluid needs to follow with the soft body, more or less.

Is there *ANY* way within blender to make a fluid simulation respect ***any*** deformations at all?

Thanks for the help!

PS: What does it mean to Apply a fludism modifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no. The fluid sim won't interact with any other simulator. But there is a way around this limitation.

For the obstacle object, selected `Export Animated Mesh`, this will animate the mesh itself, rather than simulating the mesh. As a "real" mesh, the fluid sim will treat it like any other mesh, and react to it appropriately. However, this will have to be repeated anytime you want to change the physics simulation. Incidentally, this also means that the soft-body cannot react to the fluid sim.

[image]

Comment: Does it matter if we bake the soft body or the fluid animation first?

Comment: From my testing, you don't need to bake the soft-body first. Blender seems to be able to solve the simulation together fine. But to be sure, I would recommend baking the softbody first to ensure the right geometry is passed to the fluid simulation.

Comment: Hmmm, as soon as the object hits the soft-body bowl, the fluid just becomes a cube again!  Do you know any likely causes, sir?