# Is there a way to simulate water balloon physics in Blender?

Tags: physics

Trying to animate something in Blender and I thought I might try and give it water balloon physics. I don't know how to simulate these kinds of physics so I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Could you give some reference to what you mean by water balloon physics? Edmond suggested using fluid simulation, but it seems to me you don't want the water to be visible, you just want a round object with parameters adequate for a balloon filled with water. Even if the balloon is transparent, if there's nothing else than water inside, it seems you don't need fluid simulation and just cloth with pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a physically accurate simulation ? Or just something that looks like a water ballon ?

If you want something that simulates the look of a water ballon I would suggest looking at [soft body](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/soft_body/index.html) but If you want to go in depth, You would need to put a fluid simulation inside a soft body or a cloth simulation ( but you will need a pretty buffed up computer for that ).

Comment: How do I put a fluid sim inside a cloth sim?

Comment: Sadly I can't do it on my computer, so I was only able to do one with a soft body :
Create a soft body bake a simulation and export it as shown [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6484/can-fluid-respect-soft-bodies-or-any-deformation-in-blender) then make behave as the obstacle for the fluid.

Comment: But the fluid won't have proper interaction with the soft body, the physic simulation will be cooked and the fluid will move inside.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much that you can combine fluid sims and soft bodies. You can't even combine cloth sims and soft bodies. Sadly, in Blender the soft body system is very old and can't do many things because of that, it badly needs an overhaul.

Comment: Maybe after Simulation Geometry Nodes are introduced, eventually all simulations will be migrated to geonodes…

Comment: Let's hope for that.